# How to rotate an OpenGL graphics in Haskell without uselessly re-evaluating the graphical objects?

Tags: haskell, opengl

Simplifying the reality, my OpenGL program has the following structure:

- At the beginning, there's a function `f : (Double,Double,Double) -> Double`.
- Then there is a function `triangulize :: ((Double,Double,Double) -> Double) -> [Triangle]` such that `triangulize f` calculates a triangular mesh of the surface `f(x,y,z)=0`.
- Then there is the `displayCallback`, a function `display :: IORef Float -> DisplayCallBack` which displays the graphics (that is to say it displays the triangular mesh). The first argument `IORef Float` is here to rotate the graphics, and its value (the angle of the rotation) changes when the user presses a key on the keyboard, thanks to the `keyboardCallback` defined later. Don't forget that the `display` function calls `triangulize f`.
- Then the problem is the following one. When the user presses the key to rotate the graphic, the `display` function is triggered. And then `triangulize f` is re-evaluated, whereas it doesn't need to be re-evaluated: rotating the graphics does not change the triangular mesh (i.e. the result of `triangulize f` is the same as before).

So, is there a way to rotate the graphics by pressing a key without triggering `triangulize f` ?  In other words, to "freeze" `triangulize f` so that it is evaluated only once and is never re-evaluated, which is time-consuming but useless since anyway the result is always the same.

I believe this is a standard way to rotate a graphics in Haskell OpenGL (I viewed that way in some tutos), so I don't think it is necessary to post my code. But of course I can post it if needed.

The reality is more complicated since there are other `IORef`'s to control some parameters of the surface. But I would like to firstly know some solutions for this simplified situation.

## EDIT: more details and some code

### Simplified code

So, if I follow the simplified description above, my program looks like

```
fBretzel5 :: (Double,Double,Double) -> Double
fBretzel5 (x,y,z) = ((x*x+y*y/4-1)*(x*x/4+y*y-1))^2 + z*z

triangles :: [Triangle] -- Triangle: triplet of 3 vertices
triangles =
  triangulize fBretzel5 ((-2.5,2.5),(-2.5,2.5),(-0.5,0.5))
-- "triangulize f (xbounds, ybounds, zbounds)"
--   calculates a triangular mesh of the surface f(x,y,z)=0

display :: IORef Float -> DisplayCallback
display rot = do
  clear [ColorBuffer, DepthBuffer]
  rot' <- get rot
  loadIdentity
  rotate rot $ Vector3 1 0 0
  renderPrimitive Triangles $ do
    materialDiffuse FrontAndBack $= red
    mapM_ drawTriangle triangles
  swapBuffers
  where
    drawTriangle (v1,v2,v3) = do
      triangleNormal (v1,v2,v3) -- the normal of the triangle
      vertex v1
      vertex v2
      vertex v3

keyboard :: IORef Float -- rotation angle
         -> KeyboardCallback
keyboard rot c _ = do
  case c of
    'e' -> rot $~! subtract 2
    'r' -> rot $~! (+ 2)
    'q' -> leaveMainLoop
    _   -> return ()
  postRedisplay Nothing
```

This causes the issue described above. Each time the key `'e'` or `'r'` is pressed, the `triangulize` function runs while its output remains the same.

### True code (almost)

Now, here is a version of my program closest to the reality. In fact, it calculates a triangular mesh for a surface `f(x,y,z)=l`, where the "isolevel" `l` can be changed with the keyboard.

```
voxel :: IO Voxel
voxel = makeVoxel fBretzel5 ((-2.5,2.5),(-2.5,2.5),(-0.5,0.5))
-- the voxel is a 3D-array of points; each entry of the array is
--   the value of the function at this point
-- !! the voxel should never changes throughout the program !!

trianglesBretz :: Double -> IO [Triangle]
trianglesBretz level = do
  vxl <- voxel
  computeContour3d vxl level
-- "computeContour3d vxl level" calculates a triangular mesh
--   of the surface f(x,y,z)=level

display :: IORef Float -> IORef Float -> DisplayCallback
display rot level = do
  clear [ColorBuffer, DepthBuffer]
  rot' <- get rot
  level' <- get level
  triangles <- trianglesBretz level'
  loadIdentity
  rotate rot $ Vector3 1 0 0
  renderPrimitive Triangles $ do
    materialDiffuse FrontAndBack $= red
    mapM_ drawTriangle triangles
  swapBuffers
  where
    drawTriangle (v1,v2,v3) = do
      triangleNormal (v1,v2,v3) -- the normal of the triangle
      vertex v1
      vertex v2
      vertex v3

keyboard :: IORef Float  -- rotation angle
         -> IORef Double -- isolevel
         -> KeyboardCallback
keyboard rot level c _ = do
  case c of
    'e' -> rot $~! subtract 2
    'r' -> rot $~! (+ 2)
    'h' -> level $~! (+ 0.1)
    'n' -> level $~! subtract 0.1
    'q' -> leaveMainLoop
    _   -> return ()
  postRedisplay Nothing
```

#### A part of a solution

In fact, I have found a solution in order to "freeze" the voxel:

```
voxel :: Voxel
{-# NOINLINE voxel #-}
voxel = unsafePerformIO $ makeVoxel fBretzel5 ((-2.5,2.5),(-2.5,2.5),(-0.5,0.5))

trianglesBretz :: Double -> IO [Triangle]
trianglesBretz level =
  computeContour3d voxel level
```

In this way, I think the `voxel` is never re-evaluated.

But there is still a problem. When the `IORef` `rot` changes, to rotate the graphics, then there's no reason to re-evaluate `trianglesBretz`: the triangular mesh of `f(x,y,z)=level` is always the same whatever the rotation.

So, how can I say to the `display` function: *"hey! when `rot` changes, do not re-evaluate `trianglesBretz`, since you will find the same result"* ?

I don't know how to use `NOINLINE` for `trianglesBretz`, as I did for `voxel`. Something which would "freezes" `trianglesBretz level` unless `level` changes.

And here is the 5-holes bretzel:

[image]

## EDIT: solution based on @Petr Pudlák's answer.

After @Petr Pudlák's very good answer I came to the following code. I give this solution here in order to place the answer more in the context of `OpenGL`.

```
data Context = Context
    {
      contextRotation  :: IORef Float
    , contextTriangles :: IORef [Triangle]
    }

red :: Color4 GLfloat
red = Color4 1 0 0 1

fBretz :: XYZ -> Double
fBretz (x,y,z) = ((x2+y2/4-1)*(x2/4+y2-1))^2 + z*z
  where
  x2 = x*x
  y2 = y*y

voxel :: Voxel
{-# NOINLINE voxel #-}
voxel = unsafePerformIO $ makeVoxel fBretz ((-2.5,2.5),(-2.5,2.5),(-1,1))

trianglesBretz :: Double -> IO [Triangle]
trianglesBretz level = computeContour3d voxel level

display :: Context -> DisplayCallback
display context = do
  clear [ColorBuffer, DepthBuffer]
  rot <- get (contextRotation context)
  triangles <- get (contextTriangles context)
  loadIdentity
  rotate rot $ Vector3 1 0 0
  renderPrimitive Triangles $ do
    materialDiffuse FrontAndBack $= red
    mapM_ drawTriangle triangles
  swapBuffers
  where
    drawTriangle (v1,v2,v3) = do
      triangleNormal (v1,v2,v3) -- the normal of the triangle
      vertex v1
      vertex v2
      vertex v3

keyboard :: IORef Float      -- rotation angle
         -> IORef Double     -- isolevel
         -> IORef [Triangle] -- triangular mesh
         -> KeyboardCallback
keyboard rot level trianglesRef c _ = do
  case c of
    'e' -> rot $~! subtract 2
    'r' -> rot $~! (+ 2)
    'h' -> do
             l $~! (+ 0.1)
             l' <- get l
             triangles <- trianglesBretz l'
             writeIORef trianglesRef triangles
    'n' -> do
             l $~! (- 0.1)
             l' <- get l
             triangles <- trianglesBretz l'
             writeIORef trianglesRef triangles
    'q' -> leaveMainLoop
    _   -> return ()
  postRedisplay Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- getArgsAndInitialize
  _ <- createWindow "Bretzel"
  windowSize $= Size 500 500
  initialDisplayMode $= [RGBAMode, DoubleBuffered, WithDepthBuffer]
  clearColor $= white
  materialAmbient FrontAndBack $= black
  lighting $= Enabled
  lightModelTwoSide $= Enabled
  light (Light 0) $= Enabled
  position (Light 0) $= Vertex4 0 0 (-100) 1
  ambient (Light 0) $= black
  diffuse (Light 0) $= white
  specular (Light 0) $= white
  depthFunc $= Just Less
  shadeModel $= Smooth
  rot <- newIORef 0.0
  level <- newIORef 0.1
  triangles <- trianglesBretz 0.1
  trianglesRef <- newIORef triangles
  displayCallback $= display Context {contextRotation = rot,
                                      contextTriangles = trianglesRef}
  reshapeCallback $= Just yourReshapeCallback
  keyboardCallback $= Just (keyboard rot level trianglesRef)
  idleCallback $= Nothing
  putStrLn "*** Bretzel ***\n\
        \    To quit, press q.\n\
        \    Scene rotation:\n\
        \        e, r, t, y, u, i\n\
        \    Increase/Decrease level: h, n\n\
        \"
  mainLoop
```

And now my bretzel can be rotated without performing useless calculations.

[image]

Comment: We'll need at least a little code, to see the structure of the function calling `triangulize` and the code close to `triangulize`. The interaction with the rotation code is important too.

Comment: Ok @dfeuer I will post some code. Maybe not today cause it is 4H a.m. here.

Comment: @dfeuer Done :-)

Comment: I think it's better to write your answer as an answer rather than editing it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with OpenGL, so I have some difficulty understanding the code in detail - please correct me if I misunderstood something.

I'd try to abstain from using unsafe functions or relying on `INLINE` as much as possible. This usually makes code brittle and obscures more natural solutions.

In the simplest case, if you don't need to re-evaluate `triangularize`, we could just replace it with its output. So we'd have

```
data Context = Context
    { contextRotation :: IORef Float,
    , contextTriangles :: [Triangle]
    }
```

and then

```
display :: Context -> DisplayCallback
```

which won't reevaluate triangles at all, they'll be computed only once when `Context` is created.

Now if there are two parameters, rotation and level, and triangles depend on the level, but not on rotation: The trick here would be to manage dependencies properly. Now we expose the storage for parameters explicitly (`IORef Float`), and as a consequence, we can't monitor when the value inside changes. But the caller doesn't need to know the representation of how the parameters are stored. It just needs to store them somehow. So instead, let's have

```
data Context = Context
    { contextRotation :: IORef Float,
    , contextTriangles :: IORef [Triangle]
    }
```

and

```
setLevel :: Context -> Float -> IO ()
```

That is, we expose a function to store the parameter, but we hide the internals. Now we can implement it as:

```
setLevel (Context _ trianglesRef) level = do
    let newTriangles = ... -- compute the new triangles
    writeIORef trianglesRef newTriangles
```

And as triangles don't depend on the rotation parameter, we can have just:

```
setRotation :: Context -> Float -> IO ()
setRoration (Context rotationRef _) = writeIORef rotationRef
```

Now the dependencies are hidden for callers. They can set the level or the rotation, without knowing what depends on them. At the same time, triangles are updated when needed (level changes), and only then. And Haskell's lazy evaluation gives a nice bonus: If the level changes multiple times before the triangles are needed, they are not evaluated. The `[Triangle]` thunk inside the `IORef` will be only evaluated when requested by `display`.

Comment: So far I have understood the first part. And it works ! Very clever. My bretzel rotates without pain now ! Thank you. I will accept the answer once I will be able to apply the more complicated case.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Let me know what might be unclear, I'll try to expand.

Comment: I thought I almost got it but now I'm lost. Where should I put `setLevel` and `setRotation` ?

Comment: That's ok, I've managed !! I'm using a slightly different way but this is because you are not familiar with OpenGL I think. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent The point is that instead of exposing parameters as data `IORef Float`, we expose them as setter functions that accept `Float`: `setSomething :: Context -> Float -> IO ()`. This allows us to act (or not) when a parameter changes at will.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. I give the code I finally use, in the context of `OpenGL`. Everything works very well.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'd suggest just a minor change; To include the `IORef` for level in the context as well, and pass `Context` to `keyboard`, instead of exposing the `IORef`s. As an additional level of decoupling, the internals of` `Context` could be hidden from` keyboard` and instead have functions to modify the parameters (as I see you need to update them, not just set them), along the lines of: `updateRotation :: Context -> (Float -> Float) -> IO ()`. This modifies rotation in the context by a given modification function, doing any recomputations necessary. I can expand this if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I will see that tomorrow. It's 2 o'clock in the morning here.